# In HBase what does ColumnFamily TTL really mean?

Tags: hbase

Let's assume the we have 2 CF (CF1, CF2).

Let's assume CF2 has a TTL of one day, and CF2 has 2 ColumnQualifiers.

Does this mean that during major compaction any cells in CF2 that are older than a day are automatically dropped (as long as min-version == 0)?

I'm confused because in the documentation they keep referring to rows not sure what they mean...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding from the docs, row refers to a version of particular rowkey in a column family.

VERSIONS - Max no of versions for a rowkey to be maintained in a Column Family.

TTL - Duration to retain a version of a rowkey

MIN_VERSIONS - Minimum no of versions for a rowkey to be maintained at any point of time.

I would like to explain the above three with an example. Lets say, your CF2 has been configured with VERSIONS = 100, TTL = 1Day, MIN_VERSIONS=3

So, max 100 versions will be maintained for a particular rowKey in CF2 and any version older than 1day will be removed by major compaction if no of versions is > 3. This ensures that always 3 version of a record is always there for CF2.